# Catch app closed event

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if there is an event that i can register in order to catch when the user closes an app(that is press back on the last activity or some thing of that kind).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `MainActivity`, you can override `onBackPressed()` to know when the user has pressed the back button and handle it appropriately.

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.

You can use this in conjunction with `isTaskRoot()` to implement what you described.

> Return whether this activity is the root of a task. The root is the
>   first activity in a task.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by using a service and a broadcast receiver , Ensure if you really need these to fulfil the requirements you have.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a `Service` maybe overriding `onTaskRemoved` can be useful if you want to know that the user has removed your app from the recent task list.